# Are the rules for the blanket trait implementation and for the "regular" trait implementation different?

Tags: rust

In the rust book it is mentioned that:

> We can also conditionally implement a trait for any type that implements
> another trait. Implementations of a trait on any type that satisfies the trait
> bounds are called blanket implementations and are extensively used in the Rust
> standard library.

And this snippet is provided as an example:

```
impl<T: Display> ToString for T {
// --snip--
}
```

At the same time, according to Rust's "orphan rule" either a trait or a type should be defined in the crate with the impl block. The "any type" in the first phrase in the quote sounds confusing: doesn't it contradict the orphan rule?

Comment: No, because the trait is local.

Comment: Not if you own one or both of the traits.

Comment: Ah, OK. The example implies the point of view of stdlib: in these terms the trait is local. Thank you!